Flutter Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Key length not 128/192/256 bits
How Can I solve this Error:
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Key length not 128/192/256 bits.
in this flutter code:
final String timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

final encrypt.Key key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8(
    phoneId.length > 32 ? phoneId.substring(0, 32) : phoneId);

final encrypt.IV iv = encrypt.IV.fromLength(16);

final encrypt.Encrypter encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key));

final String encrypted =
    encrypter.encrypt(timestamp + phoneId, iv: iv).base16;

Thank you.

This is because the key is not 32 characters long. Please step into your code and verify the key is 32 characters long.
The key that I used is secretkey:hapilyeverafter1234567 it should be a secret securely stored in a config file.
Also, in your code I assume the phoneId  is always longer than 32 characters. then you can use phoneId instead of the key that I used.
Essentially key must be 32 chars long it was not in your case that was the issue.
I have changed your code like below and it works.

  String phoneId = "324234234234234";
  
  //final String timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

  //final encrypt.Key key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8(
  //    phoneId.length > 32 ? phoneId.substring(0, 32) : phoneId);

  //create a 32 chars long key
  final key = encrypt.Key.fromUtf8('secretkey:hapilyeverafter1234567'); // 32 chars

  final encrypt.IV iv = encrypt.IV.fromLength(16);

  final encrypt.Encrypter encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.AES(key));

  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(phoneId, iv: iv);
 
  print('Encrypted Phone Number: ${encrypted.base64}');  

  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);
  print('Decrypted Phone Number: $decrypted');



